# Would it be fine to replace a Intel 2 Core Duo with a Intel i5?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

Would it be fine to replace a Intel 2 Core Duo with a Intel i5? Specifically:

- **Current Processor**: Intel 2 Core Duo E4500 [ID: Too old to find an ID]
- **Desired Processor**: Intel i5 4570 [ID: BX80646I54570]

I know 200pins to 240pins and socket connection for RAM and PCI Express ports. But I'm not an expert in processors, so I was wondering if anyone would know what to look out for when looking for a replacement processor.

Also some weird info from CPU-Z that I don't personally understand:

- Code Name: Conroe
- Package: Socket 775 LGA
- Model: F
- Ext. Model: F
- Stepping: D
- Revision: M0

Extra information if it matters:

- Motherboard: P5W DH Deluxe
- Manual: http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/socket775/P5W%20DH%20Deluxe/e2557_p5w_dh_dlx.pdf
- RAM: 8GB
- OS: Windows 7 (64-Bit)
- GPU: NVidia EVGA GTX 650 (SuperClocked Edition)

Comment: Probably not, as they have different sockets.

Comment: What you want is not possible.  Your talking about trying to replace a pre-Sandybridge CPU with a Haswell part.  Not only do they require different power requirements there is 750 pin difference between the two.  Both CPUs are on Intels website easily located.  We will be unable to provide you product recommendations.  **My best advice stick to LGA 775 products.**

Comment: @Ramhound ok, ok. Thanks. I don't know who is downvoting this because apparently I'm missing the most obvious thing here but thanks for the input :D

Comment: I downvoted the question you asked shopping advice which is specifically not on target.  You said you were unable to find specifications on the CPU, I was able to find them without even doing a Google search, they are located on the Intel website.  In addition your question overall shows a lack of research, while I don't expect you to understand the reason you can't use a Haswell product, a little research would have shown you have to use a LGA 775 product.  The ASUS provides a CPU compatibility list for your motherboard.

Comment: If you're even considering this, you have utterly no idea what you're doing. Basically, you can't reuse anything on your list other than the GPU, and you could probably keep your hard drive/optical drives, case and PSU. Everything else, very likely needs to get changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The limiting factor in CPU replacement is the motherboard and, specifically, the socket it supports. Looking over the information at the [Asus](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5W_DH_Deluxe/) page, it supports the [LGA 775](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_775) socket.

There may be other considerations involved (as Ramhound pointed in comment, power requirements are one), but essentially, a Core i5 4570 is a [Haswell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haswell_%28microarchitecture%29) family processor and was made to fit into a [LGA 1150](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_1150) socket. It would be like trying to fit a circle onto a square.

Your options are, if you still want to use a Core i5 to replace the motherboard and otherwise, if you plan on keeping the motherboard, to find a compatible LGA 775 processor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry if it didn't become apparent but I tried doing research. Ultimately I hope this question will help future googler's but I just didn't know exactly at what I should be looking at. :D

Comment: No problem. No one is born with instant knowledge about anything and as such, there exists certain stuff that, at first, one doesn't have any grounds or leads to search to.

Answer (score 3):

Intel core 2 duo CPU's have no memory controller on the die. The memory controller is part of the northbridge on those systems. Intel i5 CPU's have on-die memory controllers.

So you absolutely, definitely, cannot replace one with the other because they have completely different *functions* on the chips. The memory is hooked up completely differently. The motherboard chipsets are completely different. The CPU to northbridge link is completely different. It's an absolute non starter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a faster computer and are not ready to invest into motherboard, CPU and RAMs (which you would certainly have to in this case)
you can just overclock it. There will be significant performance increase and there is almost no risk especially when your hw is quite old already.
http://www.google.com/search?q=E4500+overclock&oq=E4500+overclock